# How to parse the nested Json into a MS SQL Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, sql-server, json.net

I would like to parse this Json response file coming from a rest api to a MS SQL table in C# as I don't want to loop multiple times as the files could be big.
I only need the nested block PolicyPayrolls Policy Details to be stored into a table. Is there any way I can store parse this nested block inserted into a table. How do I approach it?

```json
      {
   "ValidationErrors":[
      
   ],
   "ApplicationExceptions":[
      
   ],
   "PageSize":2,
   "CurrentPageIndex":1,
   "NextPageIndex":2,
   "PolicyStatus":"CANCELLED",
   "PayrollStatus":"OUTSTANDING",
   "PolicyPayrolls":[
      {
         "PolicyDetails":{
            "PolicyName":"Test 1",
            "PolicyHeaderId":1133,
            "GroupIdn":"",
            "PolicyNumber":234,
            "PolicyUnitNumber":16612,
            "PolicyYearDate":"2022",
            "PolicySuffixCode":"",
            "InceptionDate":"2022-01-08T00:00:00",
            "ExpirationnDate":"2023-01-08T00:00:00",
            "BillPlanType":"STIPULATED"
         },
         "PayrollDetails":[
            {
               "PayrollId":1284,
               "PayrollStatus":"Outstanding",
               "StartDate":"2022-01-08T00:00:00",
               "EndDate":"2022-06-06T00:00:00",
               "DueDate":"2022-07-07T18:59:08.0316001"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "PolicyDetails":{
            "PolicyName":"TEST POLICY 2313",
            "PolicyHeaderId":625,
            "GroupIdn":"",
            "PolicyNumber":4381,
            "PolicyUnitNumber":193,
            "PolicyYearDate":"2021",
            "PolicySuffixCode":"",
            "InceptionDate":"2021-07-01T00:00:00",
            "ExpirationnDate":"2022-07-01T00:00:00",
            "BillPlanType":"STIPULATED"
         },
         "PayrollDetails":[
            {
               "PayrollId":1200,
               "PayrollStatus":"Outstanding",
               "StartDate":"2022-01-01T00:00:00",
               "EndDate":"2022-06-06T00:00:00",
               "DueDate":"2022-07-07T18:58:06.0948818"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "PolicyUnitNumber":0,
   "PolicyYearDate":null,
   "SucessResult":true,
   "ResultCount":69
}
```

DDL

```
 CREATE TABLE [DBO].[POLICY_OUTSTANDING](
  [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [PolicyYear] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [PolicySuffix] [varchar](20) NULL,
  [PolicyUnitNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [PolicyGroupId] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [CreatedBy] [varchar](20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('DEVDB'),
  [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DC_PolicyDue_CreatedDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
  [UpdatedBy] [varchar](20) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DC_PolicyDue_ModifiedBy]  DEFAULT ('DEVDB'),
  [UpdatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DC_PolicyDue_ModifiedDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
  [InceptionDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
  [ExpirationDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
  [PolicyNumber] INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_PolicyDue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
     (
   [Id] ASC
     )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
     IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS 
     = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
     ) ON [PRIMARY]

     GO
```

Edit: Needed to parse the Json and insert into a db table in C#.

EDit:
I am able to do OPENJSON in MS SQL. But I need to do it in C# code without looping and do a Bulk Insert as I may have to process 2000 records in one go.

Comment: Provide DDL for destination table and desired final data state for shown source JSON.

Comment: @Akina added the DDL

Comment: Sorry yes need it for MS SQL. Updated above. Thank you @Akina

Comment: [JSON_VALUE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Although I provided an SQL server solution, I didn't notice C# in there before. If you think to handle this in C#, it would be easier with Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: How to do Bulk INsert without doing a loop in C#? I am stuck. @CetinBasoz

Comment: @Ditty, you can use SqlBulkCopy class. (BTW it is not clear what you want to insert as bulk)

Comment: @CetinBasoz This really helped and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Only thing I had to do was the PayrollDetails could have multiple payrolls. So it was inserting duplicate rows in the table since I was not capturing the payroll data in my table. So had to remove the cross apply for that and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is SQL server, right? Although JSON capabilities of SQL server is not much (compared to say postgreSQL), still you can use OpenJson(), Json_value(). ie:

```
SELECT pd.pn,
       pd.phid,
       pd.gid,
       pd.pnum,
       pd.punit,
       pd.pyear,
       pd.psuffix,
       pd.incedption,
       pd.expires,
       pd.plantype,
       PayrollId,
       PayrollStatus,
       StartDate,
       EndDate,
       DueDate
FROM
    OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH
    (
        PolicyPayrolls NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
    ) t
    CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(t.PolicyPayrolls)
    WITH
    (
        PolicyDetails NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON,
        PayrollDetails NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
    ) pp
    CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(pp.PolicyDetails, '$.PolicyName'),
           JSON_VALUE(pp.PolicyDetails, '$.PolicyHeaderId'),
           JSON_VALUE(pp.PolicyDetails, '$.GroupIdn'),
           JSON_VALUE(pp.PolicyDetails, '$.PolicyNumber'),
           JSON_VALUE(pp.PolicyDetails, '$.PolicyUnitNumber'),
           JSON_VALUE(pp.PolicyDetails, '$.PolicyYearDate'),
           JSON_VALUE(pp.PolicyDetails, '$.PolicySuffixCode'),
           JSON_VALUE(pp.PolicyDetails, '$.InceptionDate'),
           JSON_VALUE(pp.PolicyDetails, '$.ExpirationnDate'),
           JSON_VALUE(pp.PolicyDetails, '$.BillPlanType')
) pd(pn, phid, gid, pnum, punit, pyear, psuffix, incedption, expires, plantype)
    CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(pp.PayrollDetails)
    WITH
    (
        PayrollId INT,
        PayrollStatus VARCHAR(20),
        StartDate DATE,
        EndDate DATE,
        DueDate DATE
    );
```

[DBFiddle demo is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b895219fd9ae9cd6d4056fe9f930f718)

EDIT: I didn't notice C# there before. If you would do this in C# then it would be much easier really. You could create your matching classes and deserialize with it or use anonymous deseriliaztion with newtonsoft. ie:

```
var policies = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, new
{
    PolicyPayrolls = new[] {
    new {
            PolicyDetails = new {
            PolicyName="",
            PolicyHeaderId=0,
            GroupIdn="",
            PolicyNumber=0,
            PolicyUnitNumber=0,
            PolicyYearDate=0,
            PolicySuffixCode="",
            InceptionDate=DateTime.Now,
            ExpirationnDate=DateTime.Now,
            BillPlanType=""
        },
    PayrollDetails = new[] {
            new {PayrollId=0,
           PayrollStatus="",
           StartDate=DateTime.Now,
           EndDate=DateTime.Now,
           DueDate=DateTime.Now}
        }
    }
    }
});
```

Result looks like:
[image: Result sample]

EDIT2: I think it is like this:

You have a json file (or REST API result) that looks like the one in question but with many more items (2000+) ?
And also a table matching the create table definition on the question
You want the content of json be inserted into that table?
And you want to insert from within C#.

Then:

> Assuming databasename is SampleDb on server localhost, tablename is
> tmpPOLICY_OUTSTANDING and json comes from a file on
> "d:\temp\insurance.json"

```
void Main()
{
    var sql = @"INSERT INTO dbo.tmpPOLICY_OUTSTANDING(PolicyYear, PolicySuffix, PolicyUnitNumber, PolicyGroupId, 
    InceptionDate, ExpirationDate, PolicyNumber)
SELECT pd.PolicyYearDate, pd.PolicySuffixCode, pd.PolicyUnitNumber, pd.GroupIdn,
       pd.InceptionDate, pd.ExpirationnDate,pd.PolicyNumber
FROM
    OPENJSON(@json) 
        WITH(PolicyPayrolls NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.PolicyPayrolls)
        WITH(PolicyDetails NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON, PayrollDetails NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) pp
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(pp.PolicyDetails)
        WITH(PolicyName VARCHAR(50), PolicyHeaderId VARCHAR(50), GroupIdn VARCHAR(50), 
        PolicyUnitNumber VARCHAR(50), PolicyNumber INT, PolicyYearDate VARCHAR(10), 
        PolicySuffixCode VARCHAR(50), InceptionDate DATE, ExpirationnDate DATE, BillPlanType VARCHAR(10)) pd
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(pp.PayrollDetails)
    WITH(PayrollId INT, PayrollStatus VARCHAR(20), StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE, DueDate DATE);
";
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=.;Database=SampleDb;Trusted_Connection=yes"))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,cn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@json", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\temp\insurance.json");
        
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

Comment: `PolicyDetails` can go into an `OPENJSON` also

Comment: @Charlieface, yes it could and that is what I already said.

Comment: No I mean like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60cdf2a8b30d48090d2863a32c5499a3 see line 84. I have removed `JSON_VALUE` completely

Comment: @Charlieface, it is your choice. I explicitly included it to show that how it could be used too. In the same manner I could write Newtonsoft sample in N different ways.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I may have around 2000+ records coming in JSON. So I dont want to loop through the class to insert the data. So how will I Bulk insert? I was able to do openJson in MS SQL. But is there anyway to do that in C# without looping for each record?

Comment: @Ditty, yes you can use SqlBulkCopy class.

Comment: @CetinBasoz so SQLBulkCopy does not insert row by row? How to go about it? Can you please share. Thank you

Comment: @CetinBasoz isn't SQLBulkCopy to copy from one table to another? I am looking to load the JSON blob into a database table.

Comment: No you can use SqlBulkCopy class from external sources to SQL server (can be say a DataTable, DataReader. Source can be virtually any data source, like Excel, an OleDb connection, another database connection etc.) As per the JSON blob, it doesn't really have anything to do with bulk loading, you can pass it as a parameter where your parameter is plain JSON string. Your question is not clear I am afraid, why you said it was "bulk" I don't know. If you can explain very carefully than I might even give you the code to do that.

Comment: What I don't understand it what is your source, when you say "bulk" what is the part that needs to be treated as "bulk" etc. If it is a single JSON containing 2000,20000 items then has nothing to do with bulk for example. A simple insert would do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247397/discussion-between-cetin-basoz-and-ditty).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) Nuget package.
I used it and it's really simple; you could retrieve the entire field from MSSQL and then process it in your C# application.

To parse text as a JToken:

```
JToken token = JObect.Parse(text);
```

To read a specific value:

```
int age = token["age"].Value<int>();
```

To browse children nodes:

```
List<JToken> children = token.Children();
```

Comment: Actually was looking for ways to parse the file and insert in C# code. Apologize if I confused everyone.

Comment: How to do Bulk Insert?

Comment: @Ditty I'm sorry, I never used that library for bulk inserting. Maybe you can find something useful in the NuGet link.